# Angular throwing error while serving page through nodejs server and not when simply accessing the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to learn AngularJS at the moment.

I was working with simply loading my index.html file into a browser. Everything was working and totally okay.

I then thought that I want to serve index.html using a server and not directly access the index.html file.

I made a simple nodejs server using serve-static, but now i keep getting a XXXX is not a function error, when i access through the server, but the accessing index.html directly still works.

I used a fairly simple file to try and catch my mistake but even this doesnt work.

Can someone please tell me what is going on ?

index.html:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
    <title>ANG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" >
        <h1>This is a html. </h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
            <p>:: {{name}}</p>

            <div>
                <ul data-ng-controller="AppController" >
                    <li data-ng-repeat="each in customers">{{each.name}} - {{each.city | uppercase}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Le JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AppController($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'Usbamba Mood', city: 'Lahore' },
                {name: 'Kanika Manchanda', city: 'New Delhi'  },
                {name: 'Ud Kapur', city: 'New Delhi' },
                {name: 'Suggu Madar', city: 'Noida' },
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using serve-static to serve up the page:

server.js:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080);
```

Why isnt this working ? Why do I keep getting an XXXX is not a function error ?I'm really lost looking for an answer.

When i access localhost:8080/ i get an error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=AppController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:6:450
    at xb (chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:18:360)
    at Ra (chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:18:447)
    at chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:66:96
    at chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:53:14
    at q (chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:7:386)
    at J (chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:52:382)
    at f (chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:46:399)
    at f (chrome-extension://ejocekekgcaldnmjngfdbmbeebcekelc/lib/angular.min.js:46:416) angular.min.js:89
Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/btstrpd?p0=%3Cdiv%20ng-app%3D%22spots…it%3D%22initMainCtrl()%22%20id%3D%22spots%22%20spellcheck%3D%22false%22%3E angular.min.js:6
```

Comment: looks like some problem with server.js

Comment: @MaheshThumar, what can the problem be ? The initial data binding with the input tag still works its only the "controller" that isnt. Can you suggest an alternative ?

Comment: You're using syntax that should only be used in snippets or quick demonstration. Define a module, pass the module name to ng-app, register your controller via .module().controller(), and so on(check out this plunker template for a demo on how you should build a skeleton app - http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f). That said, a possible cause for this would be if node does some automatic minification of your scripts, thus your AppController function is called "a" in the final code, instead.

Comment: @Sacho This is just a test script i wrote since i couldnt get my angular app to work. Even though i havent defined a module name this should still work.